# no matching unique or primary key for this SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write this code

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(BOOKNO NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
BTIME NUMBER(24,22),
CNAME VARCHAR2(10) ,
BTYPE VARCHAR2(13),
TABLENO NUMBER(2),
EMPNO NUMBER(4),
ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
BDATE  DATE DEFAULT '23-MAR-13',
FOREIGN KEY (CNAME) REFERENCES BOOK (CNAME));
```

but it shows me that I have this error for creating my foregin key

> ERROR at line 10:
>   ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: You're referencing the `CNAME` column - but that is **not** the primary key of your table. Why are you referencing that column?? You should reference the primary key column (`BOOKNO`) :..

Comment: As others answer, if you want to reference CNAME then you have to apply a unique constraint to it. However if you're going to treat CNAME as unique then you'd do best to add some extra checks to it, such as guaranteeing that you can't have "John Jones" and "JOHN JONES" and "John  Jones" and "John Jones " in there. Check constraints can handle that, but you also see the problems caused by trying to impose uniqueness on natural values like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle/PLSQL: ORA-02270 Error**

You tried to reference a table using a unique or primary key, but the columns that you listed did not match the primary key, or a primary key does not exist for this table.

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(BOOKNO NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
BTIME NUMBER(24,22),
CNAME VARCHAR2(10) ,
BTYPE VARCHAR2(13),
TABLENO NUMBER(2),
EMPNO NUMBER(4),
ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
BDATE  DATE DEFAULT '23-MAR-13',
FOREIGN KEY (CNAME) REFERENCES BOOK (BOOKNO));
```

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
    (BOOKNO NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    BTIME NUMBER(24,22),
    CNAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    BTYPE VARCHAR2(13),
    TABLENO NUMBER(2),
    EMPNO NUMBER(4),
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
    BDATE  DATE DEFAULT '23-MAR-13',
    FOREIGN KEY (CNAME) REFERENCES BOOK (CNAME));
```

Comment: I Want to make the bookno the primary key, but The cname(customer name) as a foregin key

Comment: Then you have to make CNAME as Unique Key, if you want that field in your foreign key

Comment: @user2261718: a foreign key can **only** ever reference the primary key of a table - or a key that has a unique constraint (key) on it.

Comment: The original post and the answer both have3 `Book.CName` in a foreign key relationship with `Book.CName`. In other words, it's in a foreign-key relationship with itself. There's something more fundamentally wrong here than the `ORA-02270`. @user2261718 - do you mean to reference `CName` in *another* table?