# Oracle SQL: Receiving 'no matching unique or primary key' error and don't know why

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, primary-key

I'm receiving this error when trying to create a table and I don't know why: 
`[2016-07-05 14:08:02] [42000][2270] ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`

This question seems different (to me) from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535144/no-matching-unique-or-primary-key-for-this-column-list-the-primary-key-does-e), because in that question the OP is referencing a table with a composite PK, while I am not.

And while this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902152/no-matching-unique-or-primary-key-for-this-sql) has the same error code, it is because the OP is incorrectly references the primary key, which I don't *think* I did.

May someone more experienced in SQL educate me?

(A couple of things to note: 1) I know the table/column names have small errors/deviations from convention, but this is for homework, and the teacher requires I have the tables and rows declared *exactly* his way, even if it's non-conventional. 2) Yes, that's silly; but no, I can't change it or I get marked down.)

```
CREATE TABLE Student_Course
(
  Stu_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  Course_ID VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
  Section# NUMBER(3),
  CONSTRAINT pk_stu_crse PRIMARY KEY (Stu_ID, Course_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_course_id FOREIGN KEY (Course_ID) REFERENCES course(Course_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_stu_id FOREIGN KEY (Stu_ID) REFERENCES student(Stu_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_section FOREIGN KEY (Section#) REFERENCES course(Section#)
)
```

There are only two, small, referenced tables, which are:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  Stu_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY ,
  Lname VARCHAR2(20),
  Fname VARCHAR2(20),
  Mi CHAR(1),
  Sex CHAR(1),
  Major VARCHAR2(15),
  Home_State CHAR(2)
);

CREATE TABLE course
(
  Course_ID VARCHAR2(8) PRIMARY KEY ,
  Section# NUMBER(3),
  C_Name VARCHAR2(30),
  C_Description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

A foreign key is a reference to a primary key in another table.

The last constraint `CONSTRAINT fk_section FOREIGN KEY (Section#) REFERENCES course(Section#)` won't work - `Section#` isn't a primary key in that table

Answer (score 2):

`Section#` Must be at least UNIQUE in course table.

If you want to use `Section#` as a reference for a foreign key, it must be a UNIQUE or a PRIMARY KEY

[More information about FOREIGN KEY and constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to good answers, I'm posting my code which I corrected based on help here. Hope my corrections help others in the future.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  Stu_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY ,
  Lname VARCHAR2(20),
  Fname VARCHAR2(20),
  Mi CHAR(1),
  Sex CHAR(1),
  Major VARCHAR2(15),
  Home_State CHAR(2)
);

CREATE TABLE course
(
  Course_ID VARCHAR2(8) ,
  Section# NUMBER(3) ,
  C_Name VARCHAR2(30),
  C_Description VARCHAR2(30),
  CONSTRAINT pk_course PRIMARY KEY (Course_ID, Section#)
);

CREATE TABLE Student_Course
(
  Stu_ID NUMBER(5)  ,
  Course_ID VARCHAR2(8)  ,
  Section# NUMBER(3) ,
  CONSTRAINT pk_stu_crse PRIMARY KEY (Stu_ID, Course_ID, Section#),
  CONSTRAINT fk_stu FOREIGN KEY (Stu_ID) REFERENCES student(Stu_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_course_id FOREIGN KEY (Course_ID, Section#) REFERENCES course(Course_ID, Section#)
);
```